# Is a square zero matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Does the fact that a square zero matrix contains non-negative eigenvalues (zeros) make it **proper** to say it is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 10):

The $n \times n$ zero matrix is positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite.

Answer (score 6):

"When in doubt, go back to the basic definitions"!  The **definition** of "positive semi-definite" is "all eigen-values are non-negative".  The eigenvalues or the zero matrix are all 0 so, yes, the zero matrix **is** positive semi-definite. And, as Gary Moon said, it is also negative semi-definite.

Comment: Nitpicking, the *definition* of "positive-semidefinite" is "a symmetric matrix $A$ with $\vec x^{\mathsf T}\!A\vec x \ge 0$ for all $\vec x \in \mathbb R^n$." The eigenvalue test is equivalent to this, but is not the definition.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov Nitpicking the nitpicking. Because both are equivalent, either can be taken as the definition, so some authors could choose the nonnegative eigenvalue criterion as the definition of positive-semidefinite. Anyhow, this is so presuming attention is restricted to symmetric matrices.